# UNO R3 + WiFi ATmega328P+ESP8266 (32Mb memory) USB-TTL CH340G For Arduino Uno - External ESP8266 Pins

Tags: arduino-uno

[This](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33006588335.html?spm=a2g0s.12269583.0.0.5c4c4e9fviBsDu) board have pins to ESP8266's GPIOs.

What is `Tout` pin ?
On the back of the board it label pins :`GPIO12`, `GPIO02`, and **another** `GPIO02` ? a continuity test shows that they are not connected. So what is it ?

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From esp8266 datasheet:

> TOUT - ADC pin. It can be used to test the power-supply voltage of VDD3P3 (Pin3 and Pin4) and the input power voltage of TOUT (Pin 6). However, these two functions cannot be used simultaneously.

from [the pinout PDF](https://robotdyn.com/pub/media/0G-00005215==UNO+WiFi-R3-AT328-ESP8266-CH340G/DOCS/PINOUT==0G-00005215==UNO+WiFi-R3-AT328-ESP8266-CH340G.pdf) of [the Uno+WiFi board](https://robotdyn.com/uno-wifi-r3-atmega328p-esp8266-32mb-flash-usb-ttl-ch340g-micro-usb.html):

[image]

Comment: so there is a `GP1012` and `GP1O0` ? what is it ?

Comment: these are io pins of the esp8266. for example you can wire RX/TX to some pins of ATmega328p to use SoftwareSerial to communicate with the esp8266

Comment: I understand that these pins belong to ESP8266, but observe the text carefully - it goes not say `gpio12` is says `gp1012` (lower case in purpose )

Comment: @Guy.D, it is the normal quality level of the Robotdyn docs

Comment: So it is GPIO : 02,10,12 ?

Comment: gpio 0, gpio 2, gpio 12 and gpio 16. but Espressif doesn't call them general purpose io, only io, because the pins have constraints

Comment: @Jurag - see text on attached pic

Comment: sorry, I skipped io 4. should I see something different then on the pinout from the PDF?

Comment: next to ground is io 0 not io 2. switch 7 and the ESP BOOT pull io 0 LOW for bootloader mode of the esp8266